# Using SecureStorage for a Bearer Token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, maui

I have access to a custom server endpoint capable of brokering an OAuth-2.0 flow using a client secret stored on that server. The authorization token has been exchanged and now I'm holding a Bearer access token. The impulse is to store this token in `SecureStorage`, and (for example) use it something like this:

```
private static async Task<Oidc?> userInfoCall()
{
    var accessToken = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(
            await SecureStorage.GetAsync(nameof(SecureKeys.ApiToken)))
        .AccessToken;
    string userinfoRequestURI =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo";
    HttpWebRequest userinfoRequest =
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(userinfoRequestURI);
    userinfoRequest.Method = 
        "GET";
    userinfoRequest.Headers.Add(
         $"Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}");
    userinfoRequest.ContentType =
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    userinfoRequest.Accept =
        "Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    WebResponse userinfoResponse = 
        await userinfoRequest.GetResponseAsync();

    using (
        StreamReader userinfoResponseReader = 
        new StreamReader(userinfoResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string userinfoResponseText = userinfoResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
        var rsp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Oidc>(userinfoResponseText);
        return rsp;
    }
}
```

I know that `SecureStorage` is encrypted but what stops anyone from attaching to this process or tracing into this method and seeing it plain as day? Code obfuscation might make it a little less obvious what's going on at this point, but not really.

I feel as though I'm missing something important here. What would be a best practice and how can the token be consumed in a way that doesn't increase the attack surface?

Comment: As Anton points out, it would have been better to word it "... _disproportionately_ increase the attack surface."

Answer (score 1):

As Raymond Chen used to quip in similar cases, this rather involves being on the other side of the airtight hatchway. Somebody who can trace your process and dump strings from it can most likely do more interesting things than steal short-lived (they're short-lived, right?) bearer tokens. In fact, storing the bearer token anywhere increases the attack surface, as the latter now includes whatever systems you're using to store the token in addition to your process and the system it runs on. Just keep the token in memory and re-request new ones after restarts etc.

Comment: Makes sense. So maybe the code above is "as good as it gets" when you take reality into account. It's an awfully good point about how short lived this token is without a refresh, I tend to lose sight of that.